# EC2 Amazon TCPS question

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, port

HI all,

I tried posted on amazon forum for which I didn't get a response. TCPS is needed for my oracle database server to be ssl enabled. Looks like there is no options to open the port 2484 or any other for TCPS. Is this true on amazon instances please confirm.

Thanks,
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using EC2 security groups, or you have a local firewall (`iptables`) the port should already be open. Try running `iptables -L -v` to check for local firewall rules that came with the AMI you are using.

As a point of fact, it's worth noting that by default, ports on any system are "open" until they are blocked by a firewall. "open" effectively means "not blocked." That doesn't mean that they are in use; a system without a firewall can be quite secure if it does not have any programs that are bound/listening to the network, although this is not practical. (The words 'bound' and 'listen' come from the system calls [bind(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) and [listen(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) which are called by a program to start accepting connections on a given port.)

In short, if there's no firewall in the way, you may not have to do anything at all to "open" a port. Once Oracle has been configured to use TCPS, it will begin using the port automatically.